# 2 curve 2 different results

Tags: bevel

I have 2 curves name Top curve and Bottom curve and bevel with name bevel pipe. In the curve bevel i have given both the curve same bevel but the result to the top is thick (yellow color) and the bottom curve is thin (grey color). Any solution [image][image]

Comment: Have you done ctrl+a -> apply scale while selecting both curves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

- Select your curve
- go into edit mode
- with all Points selected press "w" and select "Set Curve Radius"
- Change the curve radius in the operator panel

to reset the curve radius divide 1 by the scaling factor, in this case the scaling factor is 2.048

[image]

Comment: its not working with the scale

Comment: Oh, didn't look closely enough. My bad.
when you scale a beveled curve, it automatically scales the curve radius.
You can set the Curve radius by pressing "w" in edit mode.

Comment: can you answer me in more details with image or gif

Comment: edited my answer above